# Sklearn.model_selection GridsearchCV ValueError: C <= 0

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search, valueerror

I'm trying to do parameter tuning using the GridSearhCV in sklearn.model_selection

I somehow keep getting ValueError: C <= 0. I think it has something to do with the fit method of the grid search. Would be glad if someone can help with this.

Trying to do the gridsearch on the SVR model in sklearn

Here's my code:

```
print(x_train.shape,y_train.shape, x_train.dtype,y_train.dtype)
#output: (3023, 1) (3023, 14) float64 float64

#svr model:

from sklearn.svm import SVR
reg = SVR(kernel = 'linear')
reg.fit(x_train,y_train)

#output: SVR(C=1.0, cache_size=200, coef0=0.0, degree=3, epsilon=0.1, 
gamma='auto', kernel='linear', max_iter=-1, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, 
verbose=False)


#GridSearch

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
parameters = [{'C': [0,1,5], 'kernel':['linear']},
             {'C': [0,1,5], 'kernel':['rbf'], 'gamma':[0.01, 0.05]}]

gs = GridSearchCV(estimator = reg, param_grid = parameters, scoring = 
'accuracy',cv =10)
gs = gs.fit(x_train, y_train)


Error:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-cf037d4a6af8> in <module>()
      1 gs = GridSearchCV(estimator = reg, param_grid = parameters, scoring = 'accuracy',cv =10)
----> 2 gs = gs.fit(x_train, y_train)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_search.py in fit(self, X, y, groups, **fit_params)
    637                                   error_score=self.error_score)
    638           for parameters, (train, test) in product(candidate_params,
--> 639                                                    cv.split(X, y, groups)))
    640 
    641         # if one choose to see train score, "out" will contain train score info

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
    777             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    778             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 779             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
    780                 self._iterating = True
    781             else:

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    623                 return False
    624             else:
--> 625                 self._dispatch(tasks)
    626                 return True
    627 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
    586         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
    587         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 588         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
    589         self._jobs.append(job)
    590 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    109     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    110         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 111         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    112         if callback:
    113             callback(result)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    330         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    331         # arguments in memory
--> 332         self.results = batch()
    333 
    334     def get(self):

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, error_score)
    456             estimator.fit(X_train, **fit_params)
    457         else:
--> 458             estimator.fit(X_train, y_train, **fit_params)
    459 
    460     except Exception as e:

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    185 
    186         seed = rnd.randint(np.iinfo('i').max)
--> 187         fit(X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed=seed)
    188         # see comment on the other call to np.iinfo in this file
    189 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\base.py in _dense_fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed)
    252                 cache_size=self.cache_size, coef0=self.coef0,
    253                 gamma=self._gamma, epsilon=self.epsilon,
--> 254                 max_iter=self.max_iter, random_seed=random_seed)
    255 
    256         self._warn_from_fit_status()

sklearn\svm\libsvm.pyx in sklearn.svm.libsvm.fit()

ValueError: C <= 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the C value in the parameter grid to be always > 0. Currently you have the parameter grid as

```
parameters = [{'C': [0,1,5], 'kernel':['linear']},
             {'C': [0,1,5], 'kernel':['rbf'], 'gamma':[0.01, 0.05]}]
```

And it has C=0 as one possibility. So when grid-search goes to fit the SVR model with C=0, SVR complains that C must not be <=0 (less than or equal to 0).

So change it to something like:

```
parameters = [{'C': [0.001, 0.1 ,1,5], 'kernel':['linear']},
             {'C': [0.001, 0.1, 1,5], 'kernel':['rbf'], 'gamma':[0.01, 0.05]}]
```

You can look at these examples to check how search for C is done:

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_rbf_parameters.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-svm-plot-rbf-parameters-py
- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/exercises/plot_cv_digits.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-exercises-plot-cv-digits-py

**Update for comment**:

You are using `scoring='accuracy'`. Accuracy is mainly defined for classification tasks. For regression models, accuracy is not a valid metric. Please check this page for valid metrics:-

- http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values

You can either remove scoring param from grid-search like this:

```
gs = GridSearchCV(estimator = reg, param_grid = parameters,cv =10)
```

In this case, the default scoring method of the estimator (SVR in this case) will be used which is R-squared score (Most common used for regression)

Or you can set scoring to any of the valid regression metrics on the page I linked above. Like this:

```
gs = GridSearchCV(estimator = reg, param_grid = parameters,
                  scoring='neg_mean_squared_error', cv =10)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Vivek! The value error C<= 0 is fixed now. But I just got another error that says ValueError: continuous is not supported. Is there any other way I can use GridSearch on the regression models ?

Comment: I did, man! But this shows me a message saying upvotes from users with reputation less than 15 are recorded but not displayed or something. Haha, I signed up in StackOverflow today just to ask this question. Until now I was an incognito user :)